# What is the easiest way to write music quickly on an iPad?

Tags: audio-software

If I have a melody in my head and I want to jot it down in a note on an iPad, is there any plug-in or keyboard that would allow me to input a music score quickly and efficiently? Or, at least an app?

Comment: Notes. Just create a simple shorthand, e.g. *[4/4] | G5H F#5Q B5Q | E5W |*. Bonus points to whoever figures out what song this is.

Comment: @Brahadeesh I just want to notate - write down - an idea i have. It doesn’t have to be playable aloud, although that would be cool too

Answer (score 2):

As per my comment,

> Notes. Just create a simple shorthand, e.g. [4/4] | G5H F#5Q B5Q | E5W |.

However, if you're feeling a little more artistic, I created this in an answer box at [Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/):

[image]

This is the LaTeX:

> $$\frak{\huge W}\rm{elcome\ to\ the\ }\frak{\huge B}\rm{lack\ }\frak{\huge P}\rm{arade}\\rm{by\ \color{crimson}{My\ Chemical\ Romance}}\\frac{\huge4}{\huge4}\ \bigg|\ G5H\ F#5Q\ B5Q\ \bigg|\ E5H\ D5Q\ G5Q\ \bigg|\ C5H\ B4Q\ E5Q\ \bigg|\ A4H\ D5H\ \bigg|\bigg|\ \text{(repeat ad nauseam)}$$

Not so bad if you know the language.

Comment: @Brahadeesh I just tested it on my little brother's iPad mini and it worked fine.

Comment: It would probably be easy to write a Python script to parse this notation and convert it to Musescore format.

Comment: @PiedPiper The days when I knew how to do that kind of thing are far behind me. Musescore is actually my score editor of choice, albeit frustrating at times. The team is too busy fixing all the bugs to add new features :(